# how to map the data which has array of data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire, xcode10.1

My response is :

```
  [
  {
    "menu_code" : "NDS",
    "items" : [
      {
        "unit" : "Nos",
        "name" : "Chapathi\/Pulkas",
        "quantity" : 2
      },
      {
        "unit" : "Cup",
        "name" : "Palya\/Curry",
        "quantity" : 1
      }
    ],
    "is_active" : 1,
    "image" : "nds.jpg",
    "menu_name" : "Normal Diet South"
  },
  {
    "menu_code" : "NCCD",
    "items" : [
      {
        "menu_code" : "NDS",
        "name" : "Monday"
      },
      {
        "menu_code" : "NDN",
        "name" : "Tuesday"
      }
    ],
    "is_active" : 1,
    "image" : "NCCD.jpg",
    "menu_name" : "Normal Combo Corporate Diet"
  }
]
```

Today 2 format i have .In this both format only my data will come from response.And i need to show them in collection view.

My api call :

```
func getAllCatogory(){

        TransportManager.sharedInstance.AllCatogory { (dt, err) in

            if let _ = err{

            }else{
                if let data = dt as? String {
                   let pro = Mapper<AllCatagories>().map(JSONString: data)
                print(data) // getting data
                print(pro as Any) // getting nil

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

My model :

```
class AllCatagories: Mappable{

    var menu_code = ""
    var items: Array<AllCatProducts> = []
    var is_active = 0
    var image = ""
    var menu_name = ""

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    init() {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        menu_name <- map["menu_name"]
        is_active <- map["is_active"]
        menu_code <- map["menu_code"]
        image <- map["image"]
       items <- map["items"]
    }
}
```

Below i have created one more model class for the item inside my json.

```
class AllCatProducts: Mappable{

    var name = ""
    var quantity = 0
    var unit = ""
    var menu_code = ""



    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    init() {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        quantity <- map["quantity"]
        unit <- map["unit"]
        menu_code <- map["menu_code"]
    }
}
```

The issues is i am getting nil in my `pro`.Not sure when i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try

```
struct AllCatagories: Codable {
    let menuCode: String
    let items: [AllCatProducts]
    let isActive: Int
    let image, menuName: String
}

struct AllCatProducts: Codable {
    let unit: String?
    let name: String
    let quantity: Int?
    let menuCode: String? 
}
```

---

```
do {
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
   guard let str = dt as? String else { return }
   let res  = try decoder.decode([AllCatagories].self, from:str.data(using: .utf8)!)
   print(res)
 }
 catch {
  print(error)
 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186585/discussion-on-answer-by-sh-khan-how-to-map-the-data-which-has-array-of-data).

Comment: @Sh_Khan i tried like thsi ` for data in res {
                        if let name = data.menuName {
                            print(name)
                        }
                    }` not even its going inside name . i wrote this in my `getallcat` method

Comment: @Sh_Khan any help on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434614/how-to-save-struct-values-with-codable-decodable